# Check for ' in a string in PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am sending data from a HTML from to PHP with Javascript as the middleman. I want to check whether a string contains ' in Javascript and PHP as it will stop my sql commands from working. I have tried the code below but it is not working. How do I do this?

```
function CheckQuestionAnswerField($value) {
    $isQAValid = true;

    if($value == "")
        $isQAValid = false;
    if($value == null)
        $isQAValid = false;
    for($LCV=0; $LCV<(count($value)-1); $LCV++) {
        if($value[$LCV] == "'")
            $isQAValid = false;
    }

    return $isQAValid;
}
```

In the code above $value is the string. If a false is returned from the function then I show an alert. This function is working for the first two if statement, however, this is not working in the for loop. What is the problem?

I also wanted to know how to do this in Javascript.

I also wanted to know if these implementations will work to detect ".

---

edit-1

I tried strpos with the code below its still not working

```
function CheckQuestionAnswerField($value) {
    $isQAValid = true;

    if($value == "")
        $isQAValid = false;
    if($value == null)
        $isQAValid = false;
    if (strpos($value,"'") == true)
        $isQAValid = false;
    if (strpos($value,'"') !== false)
        $isQAValid = false;

    return $isQAValid;
}
```

Its saying false on everything now.

Comment: You want to HTML escape all user input values. Should be done in both JavaScript and PHP. More than just a simple check for `'`.

Comment: Better to use `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions so that your queries will work.

Comment: Its more secure to do the validation and replacement server side instead... In PHP

Comment: ...What you *really* want is to learn how to handle data properly.  An apostrophe should not bring down your app.

Comment: @jtheman this code is implemented in the server side PHP not the HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately and apostrophe does bring down my app because I pass strings in the SQL commands.

Comment: @DreamEater could you please elaborate and show an example.

Comment: @VedaSadhak: Yeah.  Without escaping, without prepared statements, without any kind of protection.  **Stop that.**  If you were escaping data, or sticking your data in parameters insteaad of directly into the SQL, you wouldn't have to strip apostrophes; you wouldn't even have to *care* about them.

Comment: Why not just `if(strpos($value, "'") !== false)`?

Comment: @sweetamylase I have extra code that I have not posted here (because there are no problems in that code) that checks for other cases.

Comment: @VedaSadhak Check the PHP docs regarding [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

Comment: @dleiftah does lets say $value = abcde, would strpos($value,"c") return true? if not what would it do. I'm just trying to learn what strpos is...

Comment: `strpos` will return the position found in the string or `false` if not found. So you want strpos to return `false`. In your example, it youd return 2 as c is the third letter in the string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you dont want to just check if this chracter is existent and invalidate the value - you should be escaping all your queries so that the presence of this value doesnt matter in terms of executing the query. Then if you still want to disallow this character for other reasons you can do so.

Second, you can use a single check against `empty()` to check for both `""` and `null`.

Lastly, there is no reason to loop over the string, you can use `strpos` to find if the character occurs - it will return `false` if it doesnt.

```
function CheckQuestionAnswerField($value) {
    $isQAValid = true;

    if(empty($value) {
       $isQAValid = false;
    } else if ( strpos($value, "'") !== false) {
      $isQAValid = false;
    }

    return $isQAValid;
}
```

Comment: `strpos` returns `false` not `-1` if not found. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @dleiftah: yes ive been doing js all day and was thinking of `String.indexOf`. Must have corrected it right as you were posting your comment :-)

Comment: I think your example is wrong. He wants to make sure the string doesn't have an apostrophe, hence, he wants `strpos($value, "'")` to return `false` for the string to be valid. So, your `else if` should be `strpos($value, "'") !== false`

Comment: @dleiftah: Indeed. Also this could be simpligied more by using a compound condition in a single `if` statement testing against `!empty() || strpos() !== false`.

Comment: Works, I was so stupid I was checking on the wrong field, thats why it wasnt working. I think 6 hours of coding is screwing with my head.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you'd use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
if (-1 !== value.indexOf("'"))
{

}
```

And in PHP you'd use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (FALSE !== strpos($value, "'"))
{

}
```

However, you won't need this if you switch to using prepared statements: see [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: In your example is the apostophe the first character in the string? If so, `strpos` returns `0` which doesn't evaluate to `TRUE`. You need to do it the way I've written it `!== FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely escape your queries on the backend.  It's a gaping security hole if you don't.

This function was the old way to do it (has references to alternatives):
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

I would also consider using `htmlentities()` on user-submitted data.